# Jquery button click error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, mobile

I am getting a error "error loading page" when trying to place the following overloads into a jquery button.

```
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true">True</a>
```

Below is the url that I am trying to place into a jquery button.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Jobs", "Jobs", New With {.id = currentItem.Cust_UUID})
```

Below is what i am trying to achieve but i am getting the error:

```
<a href="@Html.ActionLink("Jobs", "Jobs", New With {id = currentItem.Cust_UUID})" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-inline="true">Right</a>
```

This line of code works fine but the button text is underlined and not what i am trying to achieve:

```
<h3 data-role="button" data-icon="gear" data-theme="d">@Html.ActionLink("Jobs", "Jobs", New With {id = currentItem.Cust_UUID})</h3>
```

Comment: What is the error what you are getting?

Comment: Setting the data-role="button" should remove the link from the button but it doesn't...

Comment: Doesn't look like the Razor markup is getting processed.  When you say you are _trying to place the following overloads into a jquery button_ can you tell us more about how/where you are trying to do that?  Is it on the client-side?

Comment: This is the code that is in the view.  You are right, i right clicked on the button in the browser and the url displays the string and not the destination url...